# Prevent extra spacing between lines from \raisebox

Tags: line-spacing, superscripts, raise

I create superscripts for indexes for notes manually with `\raisebox`. What I don't like is that Latex changes the line spacing to fit a manual superscript into a line. For instance:

```
\documentclass{article}\usepackage{setspace}\begin{document}
\scriptsize
\parbox{3cm}{
\begin{spacing}{0.8}
TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST 
TEST TEST TEST {\tiny\raisebox{3pt}{b}}TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST 
TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST\end{spacing}}
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
\parbox{3cm}{
\begin{spacing}{0.8}
TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST 
TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST 
TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST\end{spacing}}
\end{document}
```

creates (without the black lines)

[image]

Left `\parbox` with manual superscript (-> too much spacing in line before the superscript), right `\parbox` without (-> equal spacing). 
How can I get rid of the extra spacing in the left `\parbox`. `\raisebox` can be replaced if there is a better way. It is ok if the superscript overlaps with the text in the previous line.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use the (first) optional argument of `\raisebox` to compensate. It allows you to tell LaTeX how high the raised box officially is. So setting it to 0pt would ignore its height. There is also a second optional argument which determines the depth. The dimensions `\height`, `\width`, `\depth` and `\totalheight` can be used in all three arguments and hold the original dimensions of the content.

```
\documentclass{article}\usepackage{setspace}\begin{document}
\scriptsize
\parbox{3cm}{
\begin{spacing}{0.8}
TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST 
TEST TEST TEST {\tiny\raisebox{3pt}[0pt]{b}}TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST 
TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST\end{spacing}}
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
\parbox{3cm}{
\begin{spacing}{0.8}
TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST 
TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST 
TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST\end{spacing}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I normally use `\raisebox{verticalshift}[0pt][0pt]{text}`, but this will make the box have zero height/depth. What are the best values to supply for the two optional middle arguments to give the box *exactly* ordinary line height/depth? I would think that this is relevant if the line consists only of such material.

Comment: @LoverofStructure: You can use the dimension macros mentioned in the answer: `\raisebox{<shift>}[\height][\depth]{text}` will typeset a raised (or lowered for negative shifts) "text" but with the original height and depth. You can also do calculations based on the original dimensions if you use the `calc` package or e-TeXs `\dimenexpr .. \relax`. Also, my `adjustbox` package provides similar modificators which all allow arithmetic expressions.

Comment: Many thanks! The reason why I asked is that I wasn't sure whether the dimensions of `\height`, `\depth`, etc are those of the supplied text or those of any potential text around the `\raisebox`; it's the latter I am interested in. Could you very briefly confirm?

Comment: @LoverofStructure: Yes, it is the height and depth of the content of `\raisebox` (see the last sentence of my answer again). Macros do not have knowledge about the potential text around them.

Comment: So is there actually no way to specify "height and depth of ordinary text around as if it were there (such as `Word Word \raisebox{...}[...][...]{...} Word Word`"? If I have an entire line or paragraph full of text that is `\raisebox`-modified, I would still LaTeX to pretend that the `\raisebox`es weren't there and every line has instead ordinary default height. (I was gonna create a separate TeX.SE question for that, but I figured it's very similar to this one.)

Comment: @LoverofStructure: I don't understand why you need to do this with the text around the raised material. Simply use `\raisebox{<shift>}[\height][\depth]{text}` to make LaTeX take the original height and depth of the raised content. The height and depth of the line is always the maximum height and depth of any content, so as long the rest of the line isn't higher or deeper than the native height and depth of the raised text you will get a normal line.

Comment: Thanks. Your last sentence is key: I didn't know that the default height/depth is always ordinary text height, no matter what's in the line. With this said, if I really don't want the line height to be affected, I might as well use `[0pt][0pt]` instead of `[\height][\depth]`, because I actively want the dimensions of `text` to *not* affect the lines.

Answer (score 6):

Generally, you could use `\smash` to remove a height, such as

```
{\tiny\raisebox{3pt}{\smash{b}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you simply use `\textsuperscript`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}
\scriptsize

\parbox{3cm}{
\begin{spacing}{0.8}
TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST 
TEST TEST TEST \textsuperscript{\smash{b}}TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST 
TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST\end{spacing}}
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
\parbox{3cm}{
\begin{spacing}{0.8}
TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST 
TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST 
T    EST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST\end{spacing}}

\end{document}
```